# JSF EL condition

Tags: java, jsf, el

This is my fragment:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{}">
    <ui:include src="../includes/top.xhtml"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

My **LoginController** will redirect to the page **home.html** that extends **MainController** that have a boolean method `showComponent` so when I try to call this `mainController.showComponent()` I get a `nullPointerException` because, as I notice, Java loads the html first to see if it is calling any Java Class so when I try to access `mainController`(that is extended from HomeController, that was not yet called) I get this null pointer

. How to I check inside the fragment if the maisController is set?

Here is what I've tried so far

`<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty mainController ? true : false}">`

It always returns `true`.

Here is my MainController class:

```
package com.erp3.gui.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class MainController {

    public LoginController loginController;
    public ExternalContext ec;

    public void checkUserSession() throws IOException {
        ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        loginController = (LoginController) ec.getSessionMap().get("loginController");
        loginController = (LoginController) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loginController");
        if (loginController == null || !loginController.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/views/login.html");
        }
    }

    public Boolean showComponent() {
        return this.loginController.getIsLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

My method `showComponent()` is returning a session object property from `loginController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It throws `NullPointerException` because `loginController` is apparently `null`. If it's another `@ManagedBean`, then you need to inject it as a manged property. This way you don't need to manually grab it from the session map. Also, you should give your `MainController` a valid bean scope. Without a scope, a new one will be created on **every single** EL expression `#{mainController}`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MainController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{loginController}") // +getter+setter
    public LoginController loginController;

    @PostConstruct // Will be invoked directly after construction and managed property injection.
    public void checkUserSession() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        if (!loginController.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/views/login.html");
        }
    }

    public boolean isShowComponent() {
        return loginController.getIsLoggedIn();
    }

}
```

Then you can use it:

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{mainController.showComponent}">
```

But why don't you just access `#{loginController}` directly?

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{loginController.isLoggedIn}">
```

As to your question why `#{not empty mainController ? true : false}` always evaluates `true` is because JSF `@ManagedBean`s are **never** `null`. If one doesn't exist in EL scope, JSF will autocreate one.

Comment: because it will be lost on the next request, won't it? don't I have to access the session object?

Comment: It's apparently in the session map, so it's available through the entire session. This is true when `LoginController` is actually a `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped`.

Comment: Then it's apparently not a `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped`. Why not?

Comment: yes...I forgot the `@SessionScoped` this annotation makes the class be accessible on the entire project?

Comment: Not exactly that. The `@ManagedBean` makes it a JSF managed bean. The `@SessionScoped` makes sure that there's only one instance during browser's session. Only an `@ApplicationScoped` ensures that there's only one instance during application's lifetime (which I think you actually mean with "entire project"). See for some background information also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `loginController` is null when you call `showComponent`. Create method `getLoginController`:

```
public getLoginController() {
    (LoginController) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loginController");
}

public Boolean showComponent() {
    return getLoginController() != null && getLoginController().getIsLoggedIn();
}
```